# Change default short-key for popup ComboBox inside XtraGrid edit form in-place

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I use a `XtraGrid` which it's editing mode is `EditFormInplace`. Currently the default short key for popup a `ComboBox` that lives inside the edit
form in-place is <kbd>Alt+Down</kbd>.

I want to change this short key to <kbd>Space</kbd>. Which event should I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [`RepositoryItemPopupBase.CloseUpKey`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemPopupBase_CloseUpKeytopic) property which you can use to specify the key combination for open and close the popup.
Here is example:

```
repositotyItemComboBox1.CloseUpKey = new KeyShortcut(Keys.Space);
```

or if you are using custom layout for in-place form:

```
comboBoxEdit1.Properties.CloseUpKey = new KeyShortcut(Keys.Space);
```